# GtkBox center center contents

Tags: layout, gtk3

I have a horizontal GtkBox with three inner components

```
short left | A large mid component | medium right
```

I want the sizes to be

```
x | y | x
```

where x=max(short left,medium right), so `A large mid component` becomes centred. I tried using `expand` and `fill` for `short left` and `medium right` since, according to the docs:

> The extra space will be divided evenly between all children of box that use this option

But it really looks like "The extra space will be divided such that the ratio of the sizes ... are preserved", which is not what I want. What is the correct solution?

Comment: Have you tried [gtk_box_set_homogeneous](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-set-homogeneous)? If it doesn't help, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndreLDM: This gives sizes y|y|y. That is, the two smaller will be as large ass the largest. If the two smaller were together, they could go into a separate box, with the homogenous property. But now they are split with the large component in the middle.

Comment: Somehow i read x | y | z. Indeed ptomato answer is th right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `GtkSizeGroup` and add both the outermost widgets to it.